# Disable UIPageViewController when ModalViewController opened

Tags: xcode4, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I am totaly new to this site, but I already like it :-)

I found it by searching for a question about the UIPageViewController.

I have a normal UIPageViewController App, in which I open a ModalViewController for setting up some settings...

**Now the Problem:** :-)

If I click on the done Button on the right side of the ModalView, to dismiss it, the PageViewController turnes the page, because he thinks that he is meant by that click ;-)

Can I disable the PageViewController GestureRecognizer as long as I have a ModalView opened?

Is there a method to disable and later his recognizer?

thank you for your help in advance...

cu Matze

Answer (score 2):

It seems odd that your `UIPageViewController` would steal touches from a modal view presented over it. Unless, perhaps, you are embedding the modal view *within* the content of the `UIPageViewController`?

To answer your question -- you can easily disable the page view controller's gesture recognizers by enumerating its `gestureRecognizers` property (an `NSArray`):

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gr in [self.pageViewController gestureRecognizers]) {
    [gr setEnabled:NO];
}
```

Re-enable them later with `setEnabled:YES`.

**UPDATE:**

In iOS 6 `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll` has been added. `UIPageViewController`s that use this transition style return no gesture recognisers in the array returned by `gestureRecognizers`. Presumably page view controllers with this transition style use an underlying, private `UIScrollView` instance (it behaves just like a `UIScrollView` with paging enabled), although I haven't checked this.

Comment: Not working the gesture  recognizers property of pageviewController returns empty array :(

Comment: @Johnykutty When creating a new project in Xcode from the "Page-Based Application" template, and putting a breakpoint in `[RootViewController viewDidLoad]`, the newly initialised `pageViewController`'s `gestureRecognizers` property returns a pan gesture recognizer and a tap gesture recognizer. I suggest there may be something else wrong with your own code. Is the object you're inspecting definitely a valid instance of a `UIPageViewController`?

Comment: I found the reason it only happens when the transitionStyle is UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll. Do you know any method to disable the scroll while using transitionstyle UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll

Comment: @Johnykutty Ah good - I hadn't noticed the addition of the scroll transition style in iOS6. I'm not aware of a way of achieving what you want off the top of my head. I would have guessed to try returning `nil` in `pageViewController:viewControllerBefore/AfterViewController:` data source methods (this is how you can prevent page curl transitions), however the scroll view still performs a rubber-band effect drag. It might be worth asking a new question if it hasn't already been asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok, I have tried it by returning nil in afterViewcontoller delegate method. but its gives some strange behaviours once it returns a view controller to afterviewcontroller newxtime when I go back and come again even if it is nil the previous viewcontroller is there. :(